How to change label text onclick event in Python?
I'm a newbie trying to learn some Python.  I'd like to have a button, called button1, change the text of a label, called label1 to "changed".
Here is my code:
def changeButtonText():
    print("phase 0")
    label1.setText="changed"
changeButtonText()

When I run it, I get the output from the console "phase 0", but receive the following error:
NameError:  name 'label1' is not defined
I am using QT creator, and in fact the label does exist, it's named 'label1'.  I was hoping I could change attributes of the label (text, even styling) by referring to itself label.
Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Where is label1 defined?  Since it's not defined within that function, it would need to be a global.  Globals are, in general, bad, which is why UI apps are usually written as objects.  Perhaps you should show us more of the code.

Thank you for the quick reply!  This is the widget.py file:  class Widget(QWidget):
def init(self, parent=None):
super().init(parent)
self.ui = Ui_Widget()
self.ui.setupUi(self)
if name == "main":
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = Widget()
widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())

And this is the form.ui file:  

Widget



0
0
800
600



Widget




270
280
71
24




I'm making a lot of assumptions here, because you haven't really told us everything.  Your "changeButtonText" needs to be a method of the class that is the widget, NOT a standalone function.  As such, it needs a "self" parameter, and the label is going to be one of the object members.  Kind of like this:
class Widget(QWidget):
...
    def changeButtonText(self):
        print("phase 0")
        self.label1.text = "changed"


I think that you didn't get label1 in this function. You can get this like this: (def changeButtonText(label1):) or use (global label1) for doing label1 global variable.
